# How to handle checkbox status manually?

Tags: android, android-preferences, checkboxpreference

I need to control a `CheckBoxPreference` manually; I have to check a condition in my own data to determine if the preference can be set or not.

How can I do it? My current code is as follows, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
CheckBoxPreference buyPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_billing_buy");
buyPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {   
   if (something) {
     return true; // checkbox should be checked
   } else {
     return false; // checkbox should be unchecked
   }
```

Should I always `return false` and then use

```
buyPref.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
final CheckBoxPreference buyPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("logs");
buyPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference,
        final Object newValue)
    {
        boolean condition = false;
        // set condition true or false here according to your needs.
        buyPref.setChecked(condition);
        Editor edit = preference.getEditor();
        edit.putBoolean("pref_billing_buy", condition);
        edit.commit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

You want to always return false from this so that Android doesn't attempt to write the preference itself. See the documentation for [`OnPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) for more info.

Note that all of this will happen on the UI thread, so if you need to do anything long-running, I would throw it in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with a [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) so that the user doesn't get frustrated.

Answer (score 4):

You should always return true if the click was handled. From the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener.html#onPreferenceClick%28android.preference.Preference%29):

```
public abstract boolean onPreferenceClick (Preference preference)
```

Since: API Level 1

Called when a Preference has been clicked.

*Parameters*

- `preference`  -   The Preference that was clicked.

*Returns*

- `True`  - if the click was handled.

So your code should read:

```
CheckBoxPreference buyPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_billing_buy");
buyPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {   
   if (buyPref.isChecked()) {
     // checkbox is checked, do something
   } else {
     // checkbox not checked, do something else
   }
   return true; 
}
```

The preference manager should handle whether the item is checked or not, but if you want to do it yourself:

```
CheckBoxPreference buyPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_billing_buy");
buyPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) { 
   // this will toggle the checkbox 
   buyPref.setChecked(!buyPref.isChecked());
   return true; 
}
```

Comment: I need to do the following - user clicks on the preference checkbox, if action is successful, then checkbox should be checked, otherwise - should be unchecked.

Comment: Does your code above mean that I can not cancel standard checkbox behaviour and control the status myself?

Comment: No, it means you can.  If you set a new OnPreferenceClickListener, it should override the default action of the checkbox being checked.  My code gives a few examples of handling the checkbox.

Comment: Ok, but I can not use `buyPref` within `onPreferenceClick`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check if the checkboxes are checked or not

```
if(buyPref.isChecked())
```

> ```
> {
> ```
>
> //Do What you want
>
> }
>   else
>   {
>   Do something else
>   }

To set a checkbox,

```
buypref.setChecked(true);
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers
Nithin

Comment: Thanks, @Nithin. However I need to control the status at `onPreferenceClick`.

Comment: just cast `preference` to `CheckBoxPreference`

Comment: @Jake, could you please post an example?

Comment: I don't understand you LA_! Can you please describe? What are you looking for? If its just to check an option, or checking if a checkbox is checked, then you can use the methods as i specified. There are lot such options here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html

Comment: As I've described in another comment - I need to do the following - user clicks on the preference checkbox, if my action is successful, then checkbox should be checked, otherwise - should be unchecked.

Comment: @LA_ posted my answer from some older code I had. It should do what you want.